# How to handle variable not defined error in r

Tags: r, variables

Is there a way to evade variable not defined error in r? For example the code below throws variable not defined error.

```r
for(i in length(someList)){
  print(someList[[i]])
}
```

Can I check if a variable exists first before executing the code above. A pseudocode would look like this:

```r
if(someList exists){
for(i in length(someList)){
  print(someList[[i]])
}
} else cat("The variable does not exist")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the exists function?

```
someList <- list(1,2,3)

if (exists("someListNot")){
  for(i in length(someListNot)){
    print(someListNot[[i]])
  }
}

if (exists("someList")){
  for(i in 1:length(someList)){
    print(someList[[i]])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `exists("myVariable")` function to check existence.

Also make sure your loop is really looping! If you use `for (i in length(variable)` it will only use the last index of your variable instead of looping over it.

You code could look something like this:

```
if ( exits("myVariable")){

for(i in seq_len(length(someList))){
    print(someList[[i]])
  }

}
```